# What software generated this VFR flight plan?

Tags: flight-planning, visual-flight-rules, software, flight-plans

I recently came across this screenshot of a VFR flight plan.  Does anyone know what software was used to generate it?

[image]

Comment: this must be skyverctor.com

Comment: Out of curiosity, why the Off Topic votes? Questions to recommend a software package to accomplish some task would be off-topic, but this one is just asking what piece of software generated this particular image, which is objectively answerable and related to aviation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## This flight plan was generated with Skyvector

[Click here for the specific flight plan from your example](https://skyvector.com/?ll=36.21118692508942,-115.19384765225689&chart=301&zoom=10&fpl=%20KMEV%20KBIH%20KVGT%20KIGM%20KINW%20KGUP%20E80%20KSXU%20KTDW%20KOJA%20KTUL)

Then click "Nav Log" for the log itself.
[image]